# Request-Response Logging Not Working on Vertex AI Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm having trouble with request-response logging on Vertex AI endpoints. Previously, with AI Platform endpoints, I was able to enable request-response logging via `gcloud`, which would then store the request-response data in a chosen BigQuery table. However, with the newer Vertex AI endpoints, the process requires using the REST API to enable request-response logging.

I followed the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-prediction-logging#enable_disable_logs-drest) and made a PATCH request with the structure provided. Despite receiving a confirmation that the PATCH request was successful (as it displayed the updated configuration for the specified endpoint), the request-response logs are not appearing in BigQuery.

With the AI Platform endpoints, enabling logging resulted in a corresponding BigQuery insert job for every prediction request. However, with Vertex AI endpoints, no such job is created even after enabling the logging.

Here's the PATCH request I used:

```bash
curl -X PATCH \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://$REGION-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$REGION/endpoints/$ENDPOINT_ID"
  -d '{
      "predict_request_response_logging_config": {
      "enabled": true,
        "sampling_rate": 1,
        "bigquery_destination": {
          "output_uri": "bq://PROJECT_ID.DATASET_NAME.TABLE_NAME"
        }
      }
  }'
```

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this issue. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I've also tried using `gcloud ai` and `gcloud beta ai-platform versions update` commands, but these do not recognize/find the endpoint.

### Update

So it appears that the issue was with using the :rawPredict path on the url (see below). Using :Predict works, but it changes the formatting of the response body.

Changing:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$REGION/endpoints/"$VERSION":rawPredict -d "@${INPUT_DATA_FILE}"
```

To:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$REGION/endpoints/"$VERSION":Predict -d "@${INPUT_DATA_FILE}"
```

Creates the logs in BigQuery, however the response body is in a completely different format. A possible solution would be to update the response postprocessing using a custom handler in [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-prediction-routines).

But it is not clear how the response body is formed before it gets logged in BigQuery

Comment: Could you confirm if your endpoint has model monitoring enabled currently or previously?

Comment: Howdy @SakshiGatyan, it is not, nor has it been enabled previously.

Comment: Hi this issue might need further inspection since it is non reproducible. I would advice you to open a [ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/) if you have subscription or file an issue on issuetracker.